# How to jump to a particular flag in a Unix manpage?

Tags: linux, unix, man

When reading a Unix manpage in the terminal, how can I jump easily to the description of a particular flag?

For instance, I need to know the meaning of the `-o` flag for `mount`. I run `man mount` and want to jump to the place where `-o` is described. Currently, I search `/-o` however that option is mentioned in several places before the section that actually describes it, so I must jump around quite a bit.

Thanks.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

What I do is put a few blank spaces in front of the flag like so:

```
/     -o
```

That's not 100% reliable but you jump through a much less hoops. If you want even better success rate, try `"/^ +-o"`. That would find lines starting with blanks and followed by -o. I wouldn't like to type that weird string often though.

Answer (score 16):

I have defined this function in my `.bashrc`

```
function manswitch () { man $1 | less -p "^ +$2"; }
```

which you can use as follows

```
manswitch grep -r
```

I got it from [this commandlinefu](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/9065/what-is-the-use-of-this-switch-).

Note: the argument to the `-p` switch of `less` is a regexp telling less to look for a line starting with (`^`) one or more spaces (`+`) followed by the switch (second arg. so `$2`), so it has the advantage of working with different formatting.

Comment: This is terrific. I've shortened the name from `man switch` to `mans` and thus `men`. Easier to type ))

Answer (score 5):

Also you can open the man page on specific position from command line with

```
man -P 'less -p "     -o"' mount
```

Comment: Upvoted for being possible, but that is quite a bit more to type than to search from within man. Thanks, though!

Comment: That's pretty useful to send someone to the exact place in the man page :)

Comment: Yes, I was just thinking that if I had to open a man page in a script for some reason it would be useful as well. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

@piccobello's answer is great, but it was eating the colors in my man pages. Instead of piping to `less` (since `man` already uses `less` by default usually), I simply pass the modified `less` command to `man`:

```
function manswitch() { man -P "less -p \"^ +$2\"" $1 }
```

This retains the functionality @piccobello had in his function, but retains colors.

Answer (score 2):

When searching for flags, I have usually gone with akostadinov's answer, and typed `/  -flag` in `less`, but this isn't usually accurate. To search for a flag with a more robust pattern without having to leave the pager, I've put a binding in my `~/.lesskey`:

```
#command
\eF forw-search (\^\\s\+-|, -)-?
\ef noaction g\eF
```

These bindings go below the `#command` section (see `man lesskey`). Run `lesskey` to configure `less` to use the new bindings. These bindings cause `alt-f` to scroll the pager to the top of the file, then insert `(^\s+-|, -)-?` in the search prompt. This is a regex (see `man re_format` and [Where is less search pattern reference?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/453234/306252)) which searches for flags in the typical format,

```
    -f, --flag ARGS
        Definition
```

Then, for example, you can type `alt-f o enter` to search for definitions for flags starting with `-o` or `--o`.

Comment: Very interesting, nice answer!

Answer (score 1):

The other solutions are quite good, but also remember that man pages are just data and you can easily do almost anything with them in Linux.

```
man some-command > file.txt
```

converts the page into a plain text file you can then manipulate. I keep a copy of the bash manual as text in my bin directory so I can just load it into my text editor to search for things and copy and paste while I'm editing scripts.

Or you can pipe it into filters such as

```
man some-command | grep -A lines-after "some pattern"
```

Although it wouldn't work for you in a terminal, I (with the help of a friend) even wrote a script that grabs a man page and displays it in a web browser so I can use its navigation/search features which are way better than less.  It's a bit KDE dependent, but easy to modify.

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/54584985/kman

Comment: You might want to try `man://` in Konqueror. KDE has a manpage KIOSLAVE!

Comment: @dotancohen - Cool. Didn't know about that.

Comment: @dotancohen -I just tried it in dolphin and it also works, but displays the man pages as directories and files and launches your default browser when you click on a file.  I don't iunderstand the part about KIOSLAVE.  I tried man://kioslave and it was the same as man://.

Comment: @dotancohen - Never mind - I looked up kioslaves on wikipedia.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KIO

Comment: Yeah, KDE has just about everything. Enjoy!

Comment: posts must be self-contained. Don't use external links because they can easily be rotten (and the above already died)

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a tool that does just this, called [flagman](https://bitbucket.org/rightfold/flagman). Still in development but already usable. For example:

```
$ ./flagman mount -o
       -o, --options opts
              Use the specified mount options.  The opts argument is a comma-separated list.  For example:

                     mount LABEL=mydisk -o noatime,nodev,nosuid


              For more details, see the FILESYSTEM-INDEPENDENT MOUNT OPTIONS and FILESYSTEM-SPECIFIC MOUNT OPTIONS sections.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following script. This displays the option description or command description.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

########################
# Author: Shinichi Okada
# Version : v1.0.0
# Date: 2021-03-14
###########################

usage() {
    cat <<EOF
Name: manop
Description: This script outputs a command description or an option description from the man page.
Usage:  
    manop wget -b : Show wget -b option description
    manop ls: Show the ls command description
EOF
    exit 2
}

if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
    usage
fi

if [ $# -eq 2 ]; then
    man "$1" | col -bx | sed -n "/^  *$2/,/^$/p"
else
    man "$1" | col -bx | sed -n "/^DESCRIPTION/,/^$/p"
fi

exit 0
```

On your terminal:

```
$ manop ls -h
       -h, --human-readable
              with -l and -s, print sizes like 1K 234M 2G etc.

$ manop  uniq
DESCRIPTION
       Filter  adjacent matching lines from INPUT (or standard input), writing
       to OUTPUT (or standard output).
```